# Error: Symbian SDK Error - Failed to initialize session

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java-me, sdk, nokia

I've tried to deal with this before, about 8 months ago, I didn't find a solution for this then, and also now there is no real solution for it.

I downloaded the Nokia Symbian-3 SDK 0.8 - the newest today, I have Java 1.6.0.13, Eclipse 3.5 and winXP sp3, and when I try to run the emulator from the IDE, on the "Connect to agent" step, the debug/run fails, and I get this Error: "Symbian SDK Error - Failed to initialize session", I've looked on Nokia forums, and wrote Nokia an Email few months ago about this, but they probably don't care, since I got no reply, so perhaps someone here faced this error and found a way around it.

Here is the stack-trace from Eclipse error log:

```
java.io.IOException: Debugger launch time-out exceeded
at 
 org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.waitForRemoteDebugger(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.createVirtualMachine(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.runInDebug(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorRunner.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.mtj.internal.core.launching.midp.EmulatorLaunchConfigDelegate.launch(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:703)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:866)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1069)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Thanks,
Adam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,

That is funny that no one replied on this question...

The solution is simple, go to: Project->Right click->Properties->J2Me->Nokia SDK->Edit->
and in the combo box **SELECT** the **SymbianEmulator** and **NOT** the **SymbianDevice**, and thats it, it works.

Adam.

Comment: What also is funny no one gave any feedback or comment about this. is this helpful?

Comment: Changing to S60Emulator did not work for me. I am trying to do OnDeviceDebugging on Nokia E63. I have Netbeans 6.9.1,S60_3rd_FP2_SDK_v1.1 SDK. Any other pointers ?

Comment: It's not actually not working, that solution for " Platform home (platform.home property) is not set. Value of this property should be S60 5th Edition SDK v1.0 emulator home directory location." this error. if have give correct solution